# Getting error on alias name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why I am getting an error for this code?

```
SELECT test.name, test2.name
FROM test AS p
INNER JOIN test2 AS d ON p.id = d.testid
```

I am learning alias on tables, but it throws this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 328
>   The multi-part identifier "test.name" could not be bound.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have defined alias name to `test` and `test2` table. You need to use alias name to refer columns

```
SELECT p.name, d.name
FROM test as p
INNER JOIN test2 as d
ON p.id = d.testid
```

Comment: Thanks @prdp I am dumb :)

Comment: @JasonClark - No question is dumb.. This is quite common mistake that everyone will do

Comment: similarly i am getting the error on concatenating both tables using following code:             SELECT p.name, p.city+', '+d.salary+', '+d.age AS Detail
FROM test as p, test2 as d where p.name='john' and p.id=d.testid+122;

Comment: it shows me : Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @JasonClark It could be because `salary` is of `numeric` type. Try this way `p.city+', '+cast(d.salary as varchar(50))+', '+d.age`

Comment: Thanks again @prdp